# Discord.py Mass DM sometimes Bugs

Tags: python, discord.py

i am Making a MassDM command but it dont works well, it sends a Message not to Everyone it stops automatically i think because they turn their DM's off thats why how can i Bypass it? or how can i Fix this error?

Code

```
    @client.command()
    async def massdm(self, ctx, *, message):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        embed = discord.Embed(description=f'**Sent everyone a DM with:** ``{message}``',color=embcolor)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=delemb)
        for user in list(ctx.guild.members):
            try:
                await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
                await user.send(message)
            except:
                pass
```

Comment: Did you define `Intents`?

Comment: Yes, i think i found the Bug, i think its because people have blocked dms and the bot dont starts new DM channel, can u help me to bypass  it?

Comment: Can you try to do `for user in ctx.guild.members:`  instead of `for user in list(ctx.guild.members):`?

Comment: well, it works like before. But the bot wont create new Chats, he only text people ho have already a Opened DM's channel with the Bot

Answer (score 0):

To debug it properly, the first step would be to remove the `try, except` block and find out what exceptions are you actually getting. It's a bad habit to catch every exceptions at once. Without knowing what exception is it throwing, I'm unable to help more.

Another thing I would recommend is to benefit from the discord.py being an asynchronous package, and instead of iterating over the users synchronously, try something like that:

```
coros = [await user.send(message) for user in ctx.guild.members]
await asyncio.gather(*coros)
```

This way it will send the message to every user at the same time.

EDIT:
I also found another bug while using a loop like that. At some point the bot will try to send the DM to itself, and that is raising `AttributeError`. Make sure that you handle that, for example:

```
coros = [user.send(message) for user in ctx.guild.members if user != ctx.guild.me]
await asyncio.gather(*coros)
```

Maybe that was your issue all along.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:) Hope it helps

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def massdm(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    for member in list(client.get_all_members()):
        try:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Test",
                                  description="Test!",
                                  color=discord.Colour.blurple())
            embed.set_thumbnail(
                url="test")
            embed.set_footer(
                text=
                "test"
            )
            #delay. Set it to 10 to 20 seconds to avoid flagging
            await asyncio.sleep(30)
            await member.send(embed=embed)
        except:
            pass
        #await ctx.send(f"Messaged: {member.name}")
        print(f"Messaged: {member.name}")
```